# How can I globally and permanently disable Chrome's unsafe port restrictions?

Tags: google-chrome

The ports in the question at [Which ports are considered unsafe on Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-on-chrome) are a serious inconvenience for me. I'd like to disable the permanently, ideally by way of a policy file.

I'm running Chrome on both the Mac and Ubuntu here.

Is there a way to force these ports to be allowed that will work across Chrome updates on both of these platforms?

Answer (score 1):

From the answer to the other question: these restrictions are hard coded into the source. Thus a solution would have to include changing the source and compiling yourself, which will not survive upgrades like you want; at least not without manual intervention every time the file is changed (or with an elaborate local VCS scheme on your part (Git/Mercurial automerge/build/install)).

If you *must* use Chrome, consider just changing the ports on the server. Or if you don't have any control over that, consider asking for a change. Another workaround would be some local port rewriting so that you could in Chrome access e.g. port 10677, which is redirected to 677, and so on. I don't know how this is done though, and I believe it is a fairly uncommon request.