# How to fix ERR_UNSAFE_PORT error on Mac OS Chrome 74

Tags: google-chrome

I search a lot on Google no solution, but I found this https://superuser.com/a/1065322/929053, but It doesn't work on my Macbook pro 10.14.4 Chrome 74.0.3729.131

Any solution so far?

Thanks

Comment: So far my solution will be this [link](https://www.ookangzheng.com/allow-unsafe-port-on-chrome-mac-version/