# How to set port 6000 for chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, port

I was referring to [How to fix ERR_UNSAFE_PORT error on Chrome when browsing to unsafe ports](https://superuser.com/questions/188006/how-to-fix-err-unsafe-port-error-on-chrome-when-browsing-to-unsafe-ports), but while appending `--explicitly-allowed-ports=6000` to shortcut target, it's showing the error message below while appending `--explicitly-allowed-ports=6000` to the shortcut target path:

[image: error]

Answer (score 2):

Take out the `--explicitly-allowed-ports=6000` flag out of the quotes around the target path.

Target should look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --explicitly-allowed-ports=6000
```